# D3 selectAll looping methodology

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm replicating the calender heat map of this [web page](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318). My code can be found at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/G7DXg/)**. I'm mainly interested in the following part of the code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg") 
        .data(d3.range(2010, 2012))         // here we create 2 svg
        .enter().append("svg");
        /* style ... */

var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")           // here we select the 2 svg
    .data(function(d) {                    // and using the data already bound to svg var
            console.log(d);       // we create an array of days
            return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d, 1, 1));
        })
    .enter().append("rect")              // for each of this days we then create a rect
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
            console.log(d);   // each creation of a new rect in the console
            return week(d) * cellSize;
             })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
    .datum(format);
```

Now, I being quite new to JS and *very* new to D3, I would expect in the console to find something like

```
2010
Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Sat Jan 02 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) 
...
2011
Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) 
Sun Jan 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
...
```

As it is, it comes up with all the years first and then all the days. My question is: how D3 operates behind the scene in such apparent multiple loops?

Comment: The `.data()` function matches the data elements to DOM elements and as such needs to check all of them before proceeding. Hence you see all the years before the dates.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for replying. So there is a first "check", it creates the arrays, and then does the actual loop for both of them at once?

Comment: In your particular case, it calls the function you provide in `.data()` for each of the bound data elements before proceeding. Only after that the `.data()` call returns.

Comment: This might help a little: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/